# Reading a file and storing data in an array, then find lowest decimal value

Tags: java, arrays, file

**My problem is that I cannot find a way to correctly display the correct value for the lowest population value and the province that has it.**:

> Write a program to read in the
>       province data file into an array
>       called provinceName and an array
>       called provincePopulations. You can
>       assume that there are 10 provinces.
>       Write a loop to: read the data into
>       two arrays. Analyse the array to
>       calculate the total population of
>       all the provinces. Write another
>       loop to find the province with the
>       smallest population and print that
>       the name of that  province.

The data is store in the following manner (provinceData.txt):

```
Ontario
12891787
Quebec
7744530
Nova Scotia
935962
New Brunswick
751527
Manitoba
1196291
British Columbia
4428356
PEI
139407
Saskatchewan
1010146
Alberta
3512368
NF/LB
508270
```

Here is my Java code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Slide50 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException
    {
        File file = new File ("C:/provinceData.txt");
        Scanner in = new Scanner(file);
        int i = 0;      

        String province[] = new String[10];
        String lowProv = null;
        int pop[] = new int[10];        
        int totalPop = 0;
        int low = pop[0];

        //while there is data in the file to be processed       
        while(in.hasNext())
        {
            province[i] = in.nextLine();
            pop[i] = in.nextInt();

            //discard the \n on the line            
            in.nextLine();

            //regular processing goes here
            i++;
        }

        System.out.printf("\n\t%-16s %20s\n", "Province", "Population");
        System.out.printf("\t%-16s %20s\n", "========", "==========");  

        //print the province population report (which includes a total) using printf
        for (i = 0; i < pop.length; i++)
        {           
            System.out.printf("\t%-16s %,20d\n", province[i], pop[i]);      
            totalPop += pop[i];

            //find the province that has the smallest population 
            //and print out the province name and its population    
            if (pop[i] < low)
            {
                low = pop[i];                       
            }           
        }

        System.out.printf("\t%-16s %20s\n", "================", "==========");  
        System.out.printf("\t%-16s %,20d\n", "Total:", totalPop);                       
        System.out.println("\n\tThe province of " +  lowProv + " with a population of " +  low);
        System.out.println("\tis the least populated of all provinces.");   
    }
}
```

Here is my sample run based on this code:

```
Province                   Population
========                   ==========
Ontario                    12,891,787
Quebec                      7,744,530
Nova Scotia                   935,962
New Brunswick                 751,527
Manitoba                    1,196,291
British Columbia            4,428,356
PEI                           139,407
Saskatchewan                1,010,146
Alberta                     3,512,368
NF/LB                         508,270
================           ==========
Total:                     33,118,644

The province of null with a population of 0
is the least populated of all provinces.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two problems:

1. You initialize `low` to zero.  `low` is initialized right after the creation of `pop`, so `pop[0]` is still 0.  I would recommend just initializing it with `Integer.MAX_VALUE` (or moving it elsewhere).
2. You don't update `lowProv` as you are updating `low` value.  So it is always `null`.

Answer (score 0):

You're setting `low` to be 0. Set that to Integer.INT_MAX instead.

e: notnoop covered it. But yeah, you need to update `lowProv` as well

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to find the minimum as you loop through the file:

```
while (...) {
  province[i] = ...
  pop[i] = ...
  if (pop[i] < minpop) {
    minpop = pop[i];
    minprovince = province[i];
  }
  ...
}
```

You've gotten most of the way there with your second loop but you're setting low to be the first entry in pop *before you've put anything in the pop array* so seed the value with something like `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.